# Stop underline from getting bigger

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a currency converter app using html,css and javascript, and when text is entered into the `<input>` on the left, the converted value will appear in the input element on the right: `<p id = "converted">`.

I want to keep the underline(border-bottom) the same length on the `<p id = "converted">`. Currently, when you enter text into the input element on the left, the one on the right increases in size and makes the underline larger. I want the underline to stay the same as when there is no text in the element.

I am currently styling the `<p id = "converted">` element like so:

```
padding-right: 40%; 
border-bottom: 0.5vh solid white;
```

I do not think the API I am using will work correctly with the stack overflow snippets, but I will include a link to a codepen: https://codepen.io/oliknight/pen/XLvQow

```js
let currlet currencyArr = [];
let ratesArr = [];
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const api = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=GBP";
  fetch(api)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      for (currency in data.rates) {
        currencyArr.push(currency);
        ratesArr.push(data.rates[currency]);

        // create 'option' element here
        var optionLeft = document.createElement("option");
        var optionRight = document.createElement("option");
        optionLeft.textContent = currency;
        optionRight.textContent = currency;
        document.querySelector("#left-select").appendChild(optionLeft);
        document.querySelector("#right-select").appendChild(optionRight);
      }

      document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener("keyup", convert);

      function convert() {
        const input = document.querySelector("#input");
        let leftSelectValue = document.querySelector("#left-select").value;
        let convertedNumber = document.querySelector("#converted");

        for (let i = 0; i < currencyArr.length; i++) {
          if (leftSelectValue === currencyArr[i]) {
            convertedNumber.textContent = ratesArr[i].toFixed(4) * input.value;
          }
        }
      }
    });
});
encyArr = [];
let ratesArr = [];
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const api = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=GBP";
  fetch(api)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      for (currency in data.rates) {
        currencyArr.push(currency);
        ratesArr.push(data.rates[currency]);

        // create 'option' element here
        var optionLeft = document.createElement("option");
        var optionRight = document.createElement("option");
        optionLeft.textContent = currency;
        optionRight.textContent = currency;
        document.querySelector("#left-select").appendChild(optionLeft);
        document.querySelector("#right-select").appendChild(optionRight);
      }

      document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener("keyup", convert);

      function convert() {
        const input = document.querySelector("#input");
        let leftSelectValue = document.querySelector("#left-select").value;
        let convertedNumber = document.querySelector("#converted");

        for (let i = 0; i < currencyArr.length; i++) {
          if (leftSelectValue === currencyArr[i]) {
            convertedNumber.textContent = ratesArr[i].toFixed(4) * input.value;
          }
        }
      }
    });
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: thin;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #90d0ff, #008ef7);
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container p {
  font-size: 8em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 40%;
  border-bottom: 0.5vh solid white;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.container select {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.original {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 0.5vh solid white;
  font-size: 8em;
  max-width: 50%;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: thin;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>Currency Converter</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="container">
      <input type="text" class="original" id="input" />

      <select id="left-select"> </select>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="ctn">
      <p id="converted">0</p>
      <select id="right-select"> </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what underline "the underline" is, or what you want to keep it the same length as. A picture would help.

Comment: like i mentioned in the question the <p id = “converted”> is the element with the underline, and when text is entered i don’t want the underline to get bigger, as it does now since it is extended using padding, hopefully that clears it up is quite strange to explain

Comment: Try removing the padding and change max-width to just width

Comment: He is referring to the border-bottom on the input element on the right.

Comment: @Nathan this worked perfectly thank you, could you post as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `max-width` with `width` in your css, the percentage (e.g. 50%) `width` will stay the same, regardless of how long the converted number is. However this poses a problem regarding your overflow.

You could remove the padding, but you could still run into issues whereby only half a digit is showing at the end, depending on how big the device is:

[image: potential issue]

So you may want to either reduce the font size or experiment with width percentages (maybe 49 or 51 .. ) , or both ..

If you knew exactly how many decimal digits there would be in the returned converted number,  this would help determine an adequate size font.

Good luck, and hope this helps